# When does an insert commit with a trigger on the table?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a very simple trigger I wrote for a table at work.  The problem is when I use 'AFTER INSERT', the trigger locks the table and nothing else can write to it.    When I use 'BEFORE INSERT', the trigger works just fine.  Both versions of the trigger compile just fine, but only the 'AFTER INSERT' gives me the error when I use a simple insert statement into the 'EVENT_MESSAGE' table.  Below is the trigger and error message:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TWCC_MHE_RERELEASE
AFTER INSERT
   ON EVENT_MESSAGE
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
m_count number(3);

BEGIN

 select count(*) into m_count from event_message where event_id = 7010 and ek_wave_nbr = :new.ek_wave_nbr;

 IF :new.event_id = 7010
 THEN
   insert into TEST_COUNT
   (count, wave_nbr, create_date_time)
   values
   (m_count,:new.ek_wave_nbr, sysdate);
 END IF;
 END;
```

[image]

Comment: The error message is clear. You shouldn't read from the trigger table  . If you must to do it use view with instead of trigger.

Comment: Thanks I understand

Answer (score 0):

A [mutating](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#g1699708) table occurs when a statement causes a trigger to fire and that trigger references the table that caused the trigger. The best way to avoid such problems is to not use triggers :P

1. Changed the trigger to an after trigger.
2. Changed it from a row level trigger to a statement level trigger.
3. Convert to a [Compound Trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#LNPLS743).
4. Modified the structure of the triggers [to use a combination of row and    statement level triggers.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/MutatingTableExceptions.php)
5. [Made the trigger autonomous with a commit in it.](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-to-avoid-the-mutating-table-problem-in-oracle/5034684)

Comment: Thanks makes sense

Comment: If it helped you could you plz accept the answer so others can be beneficial with this